# Entity framework model.tt is empty

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm new to Linq to Entity Framework DB first.

I created a website with a master page and added Ado.net Entity Model, (when adding, I noticed that model.name didn't have any extension (model.)). In the selection part, I chose "EF Designer from database" selection (because there is no "generate from database" selection).

Problem is that the model.tt is missing generating classes. It is empty. It only has model.cs file in it.

(Note: I also get Error 6046: Unable to generate function import return type of the store function 'fn_diagramobjects'. The Model.edmx store function will be ignored and the function import will not be generated.)

Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: Hi. Is it an asp.net mvc application?

Comment: Linq to Entity Framework? This is new to me, too.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - that name was used a lot when it was new. EF was made for Linq, and Linq had that Linq-to-Something naming structure.

Comment: @Wallstrider Hi, it is not an mvc application. It's Asp.Net Entity Framework (database first) and LINQ..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj206878.aspx) is a very good tutorial for Entity Framework DB First. Example for a console application but it even doesn't matter because you have problems with a database.